# Setting mask to CALayer clips sublayer

Tags: cocoa

I am working on a Layer-hosting View where I'm setting up a layer hierarchy as:

```
auto view = [NSView new];
view.layer = [CALayer new];
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
view.wantsLayer = YES;
```

and then using this later as follows:

```
auto rootLayer = view.layer;
auto layer = [CALayer new];
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
layer.backgroundColor = rootLayer.backgroundColor;
[rootLayer addSublayer:layer]; //and similarly adding more sublayers
```

This works fine and I'm able to see all the layers on the UI. The problem arises when I try to apply a `mask` to this `rootLayer`

```
CAShapeLayer* maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
maskLayer.path = getPath();//sets a CGMutablePathRef
rootLayer.mask = maskLayer;
```

After this none of the sublayers of `rootLayer` show up. I've even tried setting the `frame` of the `maskLayer` using

```
rootLayer.mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rootLayer.frame.size.width, rootLayer.frame.size.height);
```

but to no avail. I've tried setting the `maskToBounds` to `NO` for the `rootLayer` but it was already `NO` by default. I can't seem to figure out what's the issue here. Does setting a mask lead all the sublayers to be clipped? I didn't find this documented anywhere. From the documentation of [`mask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410861-mask?language=objc):

> An optional layer whose alpha channel is used to ***mask the layer’s
> content***.

So I interpreted that as to mean that it doesn't impact the sublayers.

I was trying to co-relate this to what's shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/BuildingaLayerHierarchy/BuildingaLayerHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH6-SW17) in the Core Animation guide where despite setting the `cornerRadius` (a mask) to the parent layer, the child layers weren't clipped. But I'm not sure if the same applies when an explicit `mask` is set.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "documented" but yes, it does. The mask masks the drawing of the layer and its sublayers.

Comment: @matt My query was basically, doesn't the mask apply only to the layer that it's applied on? As per your comment, the answer to that seems No.

Comment: Yup, well, there it is.

Comment: @matt Ah well, thanks for the clarification. If that's the case, then would I have to create these layers as siblings instead and then apply masks, in order to be able to apply masks to the layers individually?